# How to apply different Action Bar colors to different activities?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

I am using the v7 appcompat 21 library to try out the Material Theme action bar.I use the following code for styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#3c9cd7</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#127fba</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#006db0</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

and the layout I am using is this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

In my app there are many screens with diff background drawables I want the toolbar to match those colors. I don't want to use the color flags. 
Can this be done using the xml files only?
I tried changing the android:background, it works, but the notification bar color does not change with it.

And this all is done in Xamarin Studios.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this by using XML only, then you need to create separate Toolbars for each activity with the desired colors.

Comment: I cannot create that many themes though..is there any other alternative??

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically by using `getActionBar()` or `getSupportActionBar()` to give the Actionbar a custom layout.  You could then just assign different background values of different layouts altogether depending on the Activity.

Comment: It just uses the background drawable and that can be done using the xml file...I need to change the colorPrimary as well as colorPrimaryDark